# Separation between images in Latex

Tags: image, latex, figure, tex

I have to put two images together, but the separation between them is very small, and I really want to make it wider.

My code is the next one:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

    \centering

        \subfloat[Alerta en la barra de notificaciones]{

            \label{fig:alerta-app}

            \includegraphics[height=6cm]{graphs/verificacion/alerta-app.png}}

        \subfloat[Alerta en el interior de la aplicación]{

            \label{fig:alerta-app-dos}

            \includegraphics[height=6cm]{graphs/verificacion/alerta-app-2.png}}

        \caption{Alerta recibida desde el coordinador central}

        \label{fig:alerta-android}

\end{figure}
```

The effect is shown here:
[image: Result from the code]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `\subfloat[Alerta en el interior de la aplicación]{`

add `\hspace{5.5cm}` by increasing number space will get wider